# Simple way to create a disturbance on DC power

Tags: dc, low-power, oscillation

First of all, i must say that I am a software engineer, with very-low to no experience in circuits designs, and a very rudimentary understanding of electrical engineering and circuits. 101 really.

For a software project I am playing with I have built a small physical gauge simulator using some ready-made cheap 7-LED and old needle voltage and amp gauges.
They are all powered from a standard DC 24v 3A power supply and I am using a potentiiometer to make the values change manually when i need to change them.

My challenge is the following :
Is there a simple way, without special components / devices (NOR MCU arduino/pi to make the gauges "jump" automatically and basically mimic the operation of me fiddling with thee potentiate ? Basically some kind of a DC oscillator - but random jumps are ok.

I do not have an the option (time-wise) to buy special components but I do have a lot of standard ones, ranging from capacitors, to resistors, DC power converters, diodes, LED's, Fuses, transistors (PNP,NPN, mosfet), coils, magnets photoresistors, humidity sensors etc.
On the device level I have some low-voltage motors, steppers and solenoids.
There is a bit of everything in the very-basic range of stuff.

Is there a simple circuit that can help me achieve this "jump" in the power without any code ? ( funny question for a coder - I know. but there IS a logic behind the project :- )

**EDIT I** : 
Here is a picture for better understanding .

[image]

**EDIT II** :

I ended up using a combination of 2 solutions :

A - I took a solenoid that was producing heat and connected it to a relay via and NTC ( PTC would work the same I assume ). The NTC got heaat from the solenoid and functioned like a "gate" for the relay, which also started a small fan to cool the solenoid again. The solenoid operation also made the amp jumps .

B - I Friend brought me an ne555 which I connected to relay. ( but that's an oscillator - which was a few days later )

Although these primitive methods work, I would still like to hear other advice on how to achieve that in some other way .

Comment: So basically you want to have a random signal being fed to the gauges? And the question is how to generate this signal without code, just with analogue electronics?

Comment: Have you considered adding random numbers to the measured data in software? Or is this solution too simple and elegant?

Comment: @anrieff - yes, I think this is basically it .. the signal being any range that my power supply can generate ( preferably above 5v )

Comment: @Harry Svensson - how would this help changing the gauges display ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Not sure, I was thinking about "*Simple way to create a disturbance on DC power*".

Comment: @HarrySvensson - sure.. but the disturbance ( and the gauges ) are not software based.. they are real world gauges with real world physical current and I need to change those without connecting to a computer and without any MCU . Stand-alone.

Comment: Huh, I thought you had an ADC (Analog to Digital) converter involved *somewhere*. But you're *somehow* "simulating" a physical gauge without any digital components. - My bad. This is what happens when there's no diagram.

Comment: Some power supplies will have, on the back panel, 4 terminals where the force/sense connections exist for both the OUTPUT and the RETURN, thus 4 total connections. Insert a 100 ohm resistor in the RETURN pair, and connect a 1,000 ohm resistor to your upset-generator of choice, to be randomly pulsed as you wish.

Comment: Most likely gaining up the noise of an op-amp and band-pass filtering from 0.1Hz to 10 Hz will give you wacky gauges if that's what your after.

Comment: @HarrySvensson See edit - Added image to illustrate .

Comment: @sstobbe , yes, I am after exactly that- whcky gauges. but I really am a noob on electronics and I did not really understood the answer. can you elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the simplest option would be a simple 2-transistor oscillator, as illustrated [in this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171210/understanding-a-2-transistor-oscillator).

Choose resistor and capacitor values that give a sufficiently slow oscillation.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried this method and it works like a charm .