# I need to know what the circuit does where there are 4 resistors in parallel, two capacitors and two diodes with cross links

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

[image]

I'd like to know what the circuit in which include 4 resistors, two capacitors and two diodes would do independently from the rest of the circuit if it was connected by itself to a voltage source at C3 and given two output wires at r12 and ground. What would this do on its own?

Comment: looks like an oscillator

Comment: That is an oscillator.

Comment: see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171210/understanding-a-2-transistor-oscillator)

Comment: Those diodes are transistors, and this is an astable multivibrator. The end result is a rather nasty noise in the loudspeaker.

Comment: It would oscillate at one specific frequency, and output a square wave; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Astable_multivibrator It is also the second circuit I ever built.

Comment: Those 4 resistors are **not** in parallel.

Comment: It is rare to find resistors in parallel with each other in a design. Usually when two resistors are in parallel, the design could be simplified by using one resistor instead with the same value as the parallel combination. There are exceptions, but this is just a comment. Not going to go into the exceptions.

Comment: @mkeith, except, sometimes you'll see two or three resistors of some value and size that is used in many places throughout the design tied together, and doing the work of one odd-ball value or size that is only needed in that one place.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes, on rare occasions. But I am not getting into it in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an astable multivibrator, or oscillator.

It's the part of the circuit that generates the tone in that schematics.

Answer (score 3):

Updated, corrected ...

As above, the part of the circuit you are asking about is a multivibrator, one of the oldest circuits in all of electronics.  It turned 100 years old last year.

The overall circuit ((looks)) like a variation of a "Wheel Of Fortune" circuit, so called because it emulates the sound of a game show peg-wheel as it slows down.  When the button is pressed, Q4 charges up C3 through R5, and the oscillator ramps up rapidly to its highest frequency.  After the C4-R8-R9 time constant, Q1 and Q4 turn off and C3 is all that is powering the oscillator, so it starts discharging.  As its voltage decreases, so does the oscillator frequency.  Eventually the oscillator stops.

R12 and C5 high-pass filter the oscillator square wave output to produce a "tick" sound from the edges of each oscillator cycle.

OK - still not right.  All of that is fine except for the component values.  The steady-state oscillator freq ranges from approx 60 Hz to 6 kHz depending on the values of C1 and C2.  And even at 100 uF, C3 will power the oscillator for less than 1 second, and C3 can range down to 0.01 uF, for less than 1 millisecond of holdup. So now I'm thinking it is some kind of chirp circuit, maybe a sound effect circuit for a toy laser blaster ...

Comment: You mean C4? Perhaps that's just so it starts immediately when you press the switch, not when you let go.

Comment: Yes, C4; fixed.

Comment: I was thinking of Q4 as a current source, when in fact it is a saturated switch.  I'll correct my original post.