# How to build a simple 12VDC-12VAC transformerless inverter using transistor

Tags: inverter, dc-ac, transformerless

I am looking for a circuit diagram or an explanation on how to build a 12VDC-12VAC inverter circuit without using a transformer or an inductor of any kind.

I want this circuit to be as simple as possible, many thanks.

I will be stepping up the voltage through a multiplier system and hopefully will get some small ion jets.

Comment: Current? Frequency? Isolated or ground referenced? Sine or square? Schematic for multiplier?

Comment: Try a Dickson charge pump.  It works from DC, though it does require two clock signals.

Comment: You can make an oscillator from two transistors https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171210/understanding-a-2-transistor-oscillator but its far from a nice sine wave