# Astable multivibrator and latch in one

Tags: latch, multivibrator

I am trying to design a combined function of oscillator and latch in one circuit to spare parts.
Seems it is working but anyway do you think it is OK or did you see somewhere this circuit?:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fScfJY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It works like an oscillator when NODE1 is High. Once (at 400ms) the NODE1 is pulled Low it remembers the last "state" of oscillator.
The latching function is ensured with resistors R3,R4.
The parts around Q3 are just for switching NODE1 from High to Low.

(Upper chart is Q1 and Q2 collector voltages, Bottom chart is NODE1 voltage)
[image]

Comment: It's just a standard [2-BJT astable oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/171210/330261) with a timed pull-down. You've shown that it works when the timing is `good`. But what happens when the timing of the control is placed in a more difficult moment? You don't show it. Much of what matters, I suppose, will be how this will be used. So I can't really be definitive. Just kick-the-tires, so to speak.

Comment: @periblepsis If I pull-down the basic astable the both collectors stays Low. With this one of collectors stays High (memory function).

Comment: At bottom, this is an analog circuit. Not digital. There are periods of transition where the analog interim behavior dominates. Do you care? Have you analyzed those large-scale non-linear domains? I don't see it here. Does it matter? I don't know. What matters is the usage, I suppose. I'll leave this for others to worry over. I'm interested in the margins. And it appears you may not be. So we cross purposes. My betters can have their say. I'll stand by and learn.